# Expander was not found in Xamarin Forms 5.0.0

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have an `Expander` that has always worked in my application. I updated Xamarin Forms to version 5.0.0 and XAML signaled me an error, the control no longer exists.

> The type 'Expander' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an
> assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Has it changed its name? was it deleted ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Expander` has been moved to [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/) package under the namespace ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0#c-ui-expander-and-mediaelement-moved)).

```
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
```

- [Questions related to Expander on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxamarin-community-toolkit%5D+expander)
- Official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander
- Official repo: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit