# Cannot resolve type 'Expander'

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, expander, xamarin-community-toolkit

I have an Expander that no longer accepts the Expander value in the Binding in the AncestorType property. It used to work, but since I upgraded to Xamarin forms version 5.0.0 it doesn't work anymore and Visual Studio reports me the following error:

> Error XFC0000 Cannot resolve type "Expander".

```
<xct:Expander.Header>
        <Image Source="ExpanderPlus.png" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Rotation="180">
             <Image.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Image"
                                 Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Expander}}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="ExpanderClose.png"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
             </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>
</xct:Expander.Header>
```

Comment: how are you setting the `xct` namespace is your XAML?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expander was not found in Xamarin Forms 5.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212347/expander-was-not-found-in-xamarin-forms-5-0-0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Expander` is not defined in Xamarin.Forms, you need to specify that it is defined in `xct` namespace (from [Expander was not found in Xamarin Forms 5.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66212347/)) in your `AncestorType`, similar to when you consume it you don't do `<Expander ..>` but `<xct:Expander ..>`.

```
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
```

```xml
Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xct:Expander}},
                      Path=IsExpanded}" Value="True">
```

Answer (score 2):

Since XF 5.0, the `Expander` and `MediaElement` controls where moved to the [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit) package (you can find about this on the [Xamarin.Forms 5 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0-sr3#c-ui-expander-and-mediaelement-moved)).

Please install the Xamarin.Community.Toolkit package and resolve the reference on your ContentPage header in order to use the `xct` namespace.

Comment: The OP have already installed it following-up https://stackoverflow.com/q/66212347 the issue is in `AncestorType` and not in the way he consumed/instantiate <Expander> control